# What is the difference between full SQL query and Dataset

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, dataset

Can are you explain what is the difference between using Dataset and full SQL query?

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\db.accdb");
string cmd = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
conn.Open();
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter dadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dadapter);
dadapter.Fill(dset, "my_table");
DataTable table = dset.Tables["my_table"];
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    if ((int)dr["id"] == 123)
        return true;
return false;
```

between

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\db.accdb");
string cmd = "SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE id = 123";
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command_reader = new OleDbCommand(cmd, conn);
return command_reader.ExecuteScalar() != null;
```

And is the Dataset more preferable to use in specific queries?

Comment: Unless there's more to the question than I'm reading out of it, the obvious point is that the SQL query requires much less overhead, leaving the work to the database server.  Otherwise, you bring it all to the client and the work is there.  Not to mention storage, etc.  But if you need the whole table for other reasons, then that changes the question entirely.  In summary...the 2nd example is preferable for the apparent goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can are you explain what is the difference between using Dataset and full SQL query?

In general, `DataSet`s are one way to pass "blocks" or data (rows and columns) around.  Using a `DataReader` processes the results of the query one row at a time.  Whether you use that data to create a collection of objects or some other data structure is up to you.

In your example you are pulling an entire table into the meory of the application and looking for a specific record.  In the second example you are looking for that specific record on the SQL server, which will likely be MUCH faster.

> And is the Dataset more preferable to use specific queries?

Not in your example.  you example is looking for the *existence* of one specific record, which you do not need a `DataSet` for.

In general, it depends on your usage.  If you want to pass around blocks of data and don't need to create classes than a `DataSet` is a handy way to do that quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In the queries you have above, I'd never look to see if a single record exists in the way the first one does, as it will be inefficient, iterating through each item not to mention needing an excessive amount of code.

In practice I've used DataSets when I need to return several rows of data for whatever reason as an example you want to return a list of cars where the car starts with 'A' or something like that.  For queries returning a single value you'd always use ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are requesting that the database engine provide a full table of data (`SELECT * FROM table`) and then you incur the overhead of handling the table, looping the records, etc.

In the second example, you only request one value, an `Object`, in fact.  And that is much lighter weight and achieves the same goal.

So it would appear, based on the example, that the `ExecuteScalar` route is preferable.

Only, I'd do it like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\db.accdb");
string cmd = "SELECT Count(*) FROM my_table WHERE id = 123";
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand command_reader = new OleDbCommand(cmd, conn);
Object o = command_reader.ExecuteScalar();
if (o != null && (o is Int32))
    return (Int32)o > 0;
return false;
```

Comment: Count(*) passing the whole table? I need the first fined row only.

Comment: `Count(*)` tells SQL to return the count of records whose `id = 123`.  I.e. a single INTEGER value.